# What should people do with their bodies if they fall into a vegetative state if optimizing for being useful to the scientific community?

Tags: research, legal, organ-donation, coma-comatose, euthanasia

One of the comments on [this law.SE question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/86811/if-i-fall-into-a-vegetative-state-can-i-donate-my-living-body-to-science) states that it's probable that researchers aren't interested in comatose bodies.

I've seen a few [neuroscience papers](https://www.nature.com/articles/nrn.2016.22) on determining degree of coma, but cannot find direct evidence of the usefulness of a live but vegetative body.

I would like to know what the best option (highest practical value to researchers) is for anyone that is writing a living will, between organ donation, live body donation, and dead body donation.

Comment: Welcome Random. This is somewhat unfocussed at present, can you ask just a single question as per our requirements, and show your prior research into the topic. Please take our [tour] and read up in the [help] about how we work particularly the [ask] section, then [edit] accordingly. Please hold in mind that we don't give personal medical advice (nor legal advice).

Comment: I don't believe "live body donation" is an actual thing, though I could be wrong. Certainly there are cases where family members consent to research involving their comatose relative. I don't think the general question asked here has an empirically determinable answer, though - it seems to be a matter of opinion.

Comment: You cannot donate a living being (so no "live body donation"). *Under certain conditions*, one can stop life support and donate organs if so recorded in an advanced directive and the patient is brain dead. Please note that not all comatose are brain dead, let alone patients in a vegetative state. It's easier to swim in honey than to wade through all the ethical considerations of your scenario. There are enough problems with the dead donor rule (DDR); forget the "vegetative donor rules".

Comment: As a side-note, it would also depend on the political system and the prevailing ethos. I can't help but think of the [Tuskegee syphilis study](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuskegee_Syphilis_Study) (1930s-1970s) as an example of when things got very lax.

Comment: I feel that this question is so broad and would depend very much on the local jurisdictions concerning the person in question. Switzerland, for example, has laws allowing euthanasia in certain situations, at which point you could donate organs and/or the whole body, but I am not aware of any similar legal permissions elsewhere.

Comment: There's now 0 comments on that Law.SE thread (both for the question and the answer).